# show all validation errors at once and not allow submit until fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

So, I'm using `validate.js` and I have the below on my form; which displays the error message for the first field (firstname) but that's it! How do I show all the errors at once and not allow submission until fixed?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.plastic').slideDown('fast');
    $('#contactform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // errorPlacement: function(){
        //     return false;
        // },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('.formcolumn').hide();
            $('.button').hide();
            $('.thanks').fadeIn();
            // alert('valid form submitted'); 
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

Essentially it only seems to validating the first name?

I tried this:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('#contactform').valid(); // run a validity test on the form (shows any errors)
});
```

Comment: Could you please write down the form so I can solve it on my pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#contactform').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            subject: {
                required: true
            },

            // Add more fields here


        },


        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-inline',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

                error.insertAfter(element);


        },

        submitHandler : function(form) {
          form.submit();
         }

    });
```

Edit:

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<span class="form-group">
                     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                 </span>
```

Comment: check if you have missed the name attribute for your input fields.